# Set all NaN elements in sparse matrix to zero

Tags: r, nan, sparse-matrix

What's the equivalent of the Matlab statement `X(isnan(X))=0` in R? Note `X` is of type of `matrix.csr` in R. (This is from pkg:SparseM.)

Comment: Can you post dput output frm a `matrix.csr`-object that has an NA value? I cannot get either `X[1,3] <-NA` or `is.na(X[1,3]) <- TRUE` to create such a value. (Or just post code to create such a matrix.)

Comment: I'm assuming the OP does mean NaN rather than NA because if you wanted to fill a sparse matrix with 0's where the value is missing it wouldn't be sparse anymore.

Comment: I mean `NaN` and not `Na`

Comment: Well, `Na` is not anything in R. Perhaps you didn't mean `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use the matrix.csr class? It is from the SparseM package and as far as I can tell, at least from the package documentation, there are no `is.na<-` or `is.na[` methods. The Matrix-package does document is.na-methods:

```
> library(Matrix);M <- Matrix(1:6, nrow=4, ncol=3,
+        dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), c("A", "B", "C")))
> stopifnot(all(!is.na(M)))
> M[2:3,2] <- NA
> M[is.na(M)] <- 0
> M
4 x 3 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
  A B C
a 1 5 3
b 2 0 4
c 3 0 5
d 4 2 6
```

The Matrix package is now one of the recommended packages. My impression is that SparseM is not in widespread use.

Comment: I am loading `.mat` file using pkg:R.matlab which is providing the matrix of type SparseM package. Can I convert it to something else (like Matrix package)?

Comment: If you do a google-search you find a citation to a help page for pkg:Matrix that indicates it has an `as`  method for `from = "matrix.csr", to = "dgRMatrix"` and ....  `from = "matrix.csr", to = "dgCMatrix"`  and ... ` 
from = "matrix.csr", to = "Matrix"``

Comment: Thanks for recommending `Matrix` package! I was initially using `SparseM` with `R.matlab`, and there was a bug which didn't allow to load my set of matrices into pkg`Matrix` using `R.matlab`. The bug has been fixed by the author.

Comment: So we should instead be giving the checkmark to Martin Maechler?

Comment: The author of `R.matlab` http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/index.html

Comment: Ah, another R stalwart: `> maintainer('R.matlab')
[1] "Henrik Bengtsson <henrikb@braju.com>"`

Answer (score 0):

The function in R is actually is.na.

Then you can use logical indexing just like you use in Matlab (only being careful to use square brackets):

```
X[is.na(X)]=0
```

Comment: `NaN` is not the same as `NA`. Depending on the input, OP might want to know about `is.nan` as well

Comment: `is.na` does still return TRUE for numeric-NaNs.