# R Matrix. Set particular elements of sparse matrix to zero.

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have reasonably large sparse matrix (`dgCMatrix` or `dgTMatrix`, but this is not very important here). And I want to set some elements to zero.
For example I have `3e4 * 3e4` matrix, which is upper triangular and it is quite dense: ~23% of elements are not zeros. (actually I have much bigger matrices ~ `1e5 * 1e5`, but they are much more sparser) So in triplet `dgTMatrix` form it takes about 3.1gb of RAM.
Now I want to set to zero all elements which are less some threshold (say, `1`).

1. Very naive approach (which also was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052861/set-all-nan-elements-in-sparse-matrix-to-zero)) will be following:

   ```
   threshold <- 1
   m[m < threshold] <- 0
   ```

   But this solution is far from perfect - **130 sec** runtime (on machine which has  enough ram, so there is no swapping) and what is more important **needs ~ 25-30gb additional RAM**.
2. Second solution I found (and mostly happy) is far more effective - construct new matrix from scratch:

   ```
   threshold <- 1
   ind <- which(m@x > threshold)
   m <- sparseMatrix(i = m@i[ind], j = m@j[ind], x = m@x[ind], 
                dims = m@Dim, dimnames = m@Dimnames, 
                index1 = FALSE, 
                giveCsparse = FALSE, 
                check = FALSE)
   ```

   It takes **only ~ 6 sec** and **needs ~ 5gb additional** RAM.

**The question is - can we do better?** Especially interesting, whether, can we do this with less RAM usage? It would be perfect if will be able to perform this **in place**.

Comment: What if you just try `m@x[m@x < threshold]<-0`?

Comment: this is not suitable, because we will keep zeros. Try `str(m)` - it will have same number of non-zero elements and indices.

Comment: Sure, but you then adjust the `i` and `j` slots accordingly, just like @Roland's answer.

Comment: thx! for some reason didn't guess such trick by myself :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
library(Matrix)
m <- Matrix(0+1:28, nrow = 4)
m[-3,c(2,4:5,7)] <- m[ 3, 1:4] <- m[1:3, 6] <- 0
(m <- as(m, "dgTMatrix"))
m
#4 x 7 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
#
#[1,] 1 .  9 .  .  .  .
#[2,] 2 . 10 .  .  .  .
#[3,] . .  . . 19  . 27
#[4,] 4 . 12 .  . 24  .

threshold <- 5
ind <- m@x <= threshold
m@x <- m@x[!ind]
m@i <- m@i[!ind]
m@j <- m@j[!ind]
m
#4 x 7 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
#
#[1,] . .  9 .  .  .  .
#[2,] . . 10 .  .  .  .
#[3,] . .  . . 19  . 27
#[4,] . . 12 .  . 24  .
```

You only need the RAM for the `ind` vector. If you want to avoid that, you need a loop (probably in Rcpp for performance).

Comment: +1. This should also reduce the size of the matrix. A little improvement is to change `ind <- m@x > threshold` and then subsetting with `ind` rather than `!ind`, to save some RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this question.

The Matrix package includes the `drop0()` function, used as follows:

```
threshold <- th
m <- drop0(m, tol = th)
```

Which seems to work well.